# How to solve 'list index out of range'

Tags: python

I have been trying to figure out this error, but I cannot. I am trying to read line by line of code from a text file using a variable, so that I can get to a specific line when needed.

```
Classroom = input("What classrooms results do you want to see? classone, classtwo or classthree?")
Class = open(Classroom +".txt", "r")
lineno = 0
name = Class.readlines()[lineno]
print(name)
lineno += 1

a = Class.readlines()[lineno]
print(a)
lineno += 1

b = Class.readlines()[lineno]
print(b)
lineno += 1

c = Class.readlines()[lineno]
print(c)
lineno += 1
```

This is the text file is:

```
Patrick
6
6
7
James
7
7
7
Tom
5
9
8
Florence
4
9
3
Hannah
2
2
1
```

How can I get past the error?

Comment: Why would you `readlines()` more than once, and expect that to work? See e.g. http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html

Comment: Please explain the layout of your input file. I assumed one line per pupil in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`readlines` will read up to the end of the file. A second call will give you no data.

There is no need to use `readlines`. Just iterate over the file itself.

```
with open(classroom + '.txt') as classdata:
    for line in classdata:
        print(line)
```

You might want to read [readlines considered silly](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html).

---

The layout of your input file is not clear. The edit from another user might or might not have been wrong. I assumed the following

```
Patrick 6 6 7 
James 7 7 7 
Tom 5 9 8
```

If you want to split each line at whitespaces just use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and print the individual elements.

```
with open(classroom + '.txt') as classdata:
    for line in classdata:
        for value in line.split():
            print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to [readlines considered silly](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html).  This is a philosophy that I've held for awhile (I frequently need to read arbitrarily-large logfiles, gigs in size sometimes, if log rotation wasn't set up right) and both gives me some ammunition to support my approach and ways around it.

Comment: Then a shout out to @johnrsharpe! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Classroom = input("What classrooms results do you want to see? classone, classtwo or classthree?")
with open(Classroom +".txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print line
```

Try not using  keywords like class(Although you've used Class).

Answer (score 0):

first thing, the data files are not in the best order to be parsed easily, and there's no need to have separate files for each classroom. just include the classroom name as a column in one data file. have the tests line up one per column. I prefer to use , or | in my csv files as I hardly ever see space delimited files in the real world.

```
class,student,a,b,c
one,Patrick,6,6,7
one,James,7,7,7
one,Tom,5,9,8
one,Florence,4,9,3
one,Hannah,2,2,1
```

ok we now that we have a normalized csv file, lets use the csv module to parse it.

```
import csv
results = []
with open("classone.txt", "r") as classroom:
    reader = csv.DictReader(classroom, delimiter=',')
    col = reader.fieldnames
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        results.append([row['class'], row['student'], row['a'], row['b'], row['c']])
```

the data is now loaded up into a list and you have the headers of each inner list in the col variable.  now this is definitely not the best way of getting to the data (for large datasets i use the pandas library)  but for quick and dirty access you can do.

```
classroom = input("What classrooms results do you want to see? one, two or three?")
for row in results:
    if row[col.index('class')] == classroom:
        print row
```

you can then use the diff col names inside that col.index() call to access the various bits of data you need.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use readlines() as it makes it very difficult to seperate when they are in an array. Instead use a looping function and read each line seperately using read(). Use:

```
Classroom = input("What classrooms results do you want to see? classone, classtwo or classthree?")
Class = open(Classroom +".txt", "r")
for x in range(len(Class.readlines())):
    name = Class.read()
    print(name)
```

Comment: `readlines` reads up to the end of the file. Use `for line in Class: print(line)` (`Class` is a bad name BTW).